# Flutter AnimatedSwitcher with Scaffold

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to do beautiful navigation in my application, but when I try to implement AnimatedSwithcer on my manager page, it just displays nothing...

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
    transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: Container(
          key: ValueKey<int>(_bodyIndex),
          child: returnBody(),
        ),
      );
    },
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  ),
```

returnbody function:

```
Widget returnBody() {
if (widget.user != null) {
  var page = ProfilePage(user: widget.user!);

  widget.user = null;
  return page;
} else if (_bodyIndex == 0) {
  return FeedPage(
    key: ValueKey(_bodyIndex),
  );
} else if (_bodyIndex == 1) {
  return SearchPage(
    key: ValueKey(_bodyIndex),
  );
} else if (_bodyIndex == 2) {
  return ChatsPage(
    key: ValueKey(_bodyIndex),
  );
} else if (_bodyIndex == 3) {
  return AccountPageManager(
    key: ValueKey(_bodyIndex),
  );
}
return Container(
  key: ValueKey(_bodyIndex),
);
```

}

Maybe this is because pages are scaffolds... The question is how to solve this problem and are there any ways to do a beautiful navigation without manager page. Cause I want to have animated bottom bar and if I will add individual bottom bar to each page, animation would not be shown I guess. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to make navigation with Get package, and I need to do fade in transition between pages

Comment: Which Widget is returned in your returnBody function?

Comment: if any of them returns, they don't display

Comment: Can you remove the transitionBuilder? Maybe your animation is broken.

Comment: Nope, without transitionBuilder it still doesn't work :(